# How can I combine PC and PS5 headphone audio?

Tags: audio, playstation

I tried using one of these

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00DIGCZ3S](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DIGCZ3S)

in order to be able to listen to the audio of both my PC and PS5. It works pretty well for the most part. However, it does considerably lower the PC's volume. (Curiously, the PS5 volume is unaffected, regardless of which way the devices are plugged into the splitter.) As a consequence, whenever I disconnect or turn off the PS5 the volume from the PC will suddenly drastically jump. What's more, when the PS5 notices that it's not outputting any audio—for example in the main menu when menu music is disabled—it'll also disconnect the audio; presumably to preserve controller battery. So if I'm listening to music from the PC I frequently get deafening volume spikes.

One remedy I've tried is to connect to my monitor's audio port instead. At least the PS5 doesn't toggle the signal there all the time. But then the PS5 refuses to output headset audio. So I don't get proper 3D audio which is kind of a deal breaker.

Does anybody know what's causing this drop in the PC's volume? Might using a different splitter  help?

Comment: Just a suggestion to try: plug your PS5 analog audio out into your PC's analog audio in jack (usually a blue 1/8" jack).  Plug your headphones into your PC's headphone/audio out jack (green 1/8" jack). Then, use your PC's audio settings/volume control as a mixer to balance the audio coming from your PS5 and your PC to your headphones.

Comment: This basically works. Though now I have two mic input signals, one from my headset and one from the PS5. My computer currently only listens to the PS5 signal and plays it back. The headset input is discarded. Do you know if there's a way to still use the headset for voice?

Comment: On further examination, this isn't quite right. The 3D audio doesn't come through properly. Sounds that are supposed to come from behind are instead just dampened.

Comment: The PC is probably stripping out the 3D effects when converting from analog to digital back to analog.  You would need an analog mixer to preserve them.

Answer (score 1):

Sources sound differently because their impedance differs. In short, it's resistance for alternating signals. Combining devices with different impedance in single circuit causes imbalance in power.
That's generally not comfortable situation for devices but you can balance it with loudness control. It's safe as long you'll stay inside 20-80% of volume range.

If you're unable to balance it with just loudness change in console and/or PC, then you can use applications allowing for audio mixing in real time ie.: Voicemeeter from VB-Audio. It will allow you to plug both microphone and PS5 to your PC and play them along with PC audio.
VB Virtual Cable (technology behind Voicemeeter) has pretty low latency, and if you're not playing in rhythmic games you shouldn't notice any difference. (And if you do - there's still calibration, added latency is quite cosmetic ;) )

Answer (score 0):

For my streaming setup I use an HDMI splitter and audio extractor with an optical output. Then I use an optical to analog DAC to go from that to the aux input on the PC. Here's a link to the ones that I use:

The HDMI Splitter
https://amzn.to/3jnwK4y
The Optical DAC
https://amzn.to/3rsYvLN
3.5mm Aux Patch Cable
https://amzn.to/36Ris78

I have the XBOX One X and PS5 going through the HDMI splitter, the optical out from the splitter going to the optical DAC and an 3.5 mm patch cable going from the DAC to the PC aux input (blue connector).

In sound control panel under recording devices select the aux input and right click and select properties. Select the listen tab and check the listen to this device. Select the device that you want to listen - in my case its my headphones.

Comment: Please do not use shortened URL links in your questions or answers as because these are often abused they get flagged by our spam prevention system.